# How to save Files content in Database table with File type in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, drop-down-menu

I have table 'Artifact' with columns

**ID**   **File Type**                     **CONTENT**
1   Experience Certifacte        Some data in varbinary type

In UI, i have one row in html table which was one column was'drop down list'  file type contains items of file types like Experience certificate, Appreciation Certificate etc., and one 'upload file' control..

```
 dropdownlist   <input type="file"/>
 dropdownlist    <input type="file/>
 etc.,......................
 .............................
```

And one button to add more files , which adds same above row.

Now I want to Insert multiple files content with file type.

I can Insert multiple files content in 'CONTENT' column in Artifact table like

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FileUpload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file_Uploader)
    {
              if (file_Uploader != null && file_Uploader.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                         foreach(var item in file_Uploader)
                          {
                              var content = new byte[item .ContentLength];
                              item .InputStream.Read(content, 0, file_Uploader.ContentLength);


                              var document= reslandEntities.ARTIFACT.Where(m => m.ID == 1).SingleOrDefault();
                              document.CONTENT = item.ToArray();
                              document.filetype= ?? // How to save file type with same file

                              reslandEntities.SaveChanges();

                      }


                }
    }
```

But the Problem is , How to save files content with drop down list file types,i mean, how to get the file types and save with same row with file content in database table?
Anybody have idea? Please help me?

Comment: pass the selected value of your dropdownlist to the Action as an additional Parameter ?

Comment: i have multiple dropdownlists which was i have  to send collection and multiple files is also collection to send as parameter, but how to save both same time

Comment: are they at the same index ? or das the order of values Change ? if it is fix order than the file index is the Dropdown index or not ?

Comment: yes it will be same index, can we send content as model?

Comment: what do you mean ? Content as model ?

Comment: i dont know what you mean by Content as model

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59266/discussion-between-sanjay-and-s-l).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

Just Add Property in the model as

```
    public class EmployeeModel
    {
    public int ArtifactId { get; set; } //For Dropdown list
    public HttpPostedFileBase FileContent { get; set; } // For uploading file.
    }
```

in View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetFiles", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class="form" }))
   {
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ArtifactId, Model.getDocumenttype())</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FileContent, new { @type = "file" })</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="submit" id="btnSave" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
 }
```

and for Controller Acton method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetFiles(EmployeeModel model)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I have got the solution as above.
But, is it possible to send model using jquery like

```
 var model = $('.form').serialize();
```

i have tried , but not getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Pass Model to HttpPost Method Like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file_Uploader, ClassName Model)
{
     if (file_Uploader != null && file_Uploader.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                     foreach(var item in file_Uploader)
                      {
                          var content = new byte[item .ContentLength];
                          item .InputStream.Read(content, 0, file_Uploader.ContentLength);


                          var document= reslandEntities.ARTIFACT.Where(m => m.ID == 1).SingleOrDefault();
                          document.CONTENT = item.ToArray();
                          document.filetype=Model.dropdownlistID;
                        }
                      reslandEntities.SaveChanges();
                  }
            }
}
```

Comment: it is not one drop down list to send one drop down id , the rows will have multiple drop down lists, i have to save file content with same index row of drop down list type, how it is possible?

Comment: Can you Show me Your Model?

Comment: @Html.DropdownlistFor(m=>m.Getdocument[i].Artifact,(SelectList)Model.GetFileTypes) and another column <input type="file"/> when we click on 'Add more files' button in script i am take copy of that row as table.clone using jQuery and appending to the table with increasing index number.

Comment: For this requirement  I suggest you to use viewbag or viewdata store details on add button click and after that from that viewbag final submit to database